# style binding dynamic, 4 different color

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding

I want to style my tabel like this: [image]

I try this code, but for 2 colors.

```
 <table *ngFor="let item of notif">
   <tr class="cell" [style.border-color]="item.alarmnr === 1 ? 'green' : 'red' ">
   </tr>
 </table>
```

But I need for 4 or more color.

I have 4 alarmnrumber,

```
 alarmnr = 1 --> red
 alarmnr = 2 --> blue
 alarmnr = 3 --> yellow
 alarmnr = 4  --> green
```

How to implement? Can you suggest me any idea please?

Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to do a function in the component something like this :

```
getColorByAlarmnr(alarmnr: number) : string {
  switch(alarmnr){
    case 1 : return 'red';
    case 2 : return 'blue';
    case 3 : return 'yellow';
    case 4 : return 'green'
  }
}
```

and in the html :

```
 <table *ngFor="let item of notif">
   <tr class="cell" [style.border-color]="getColorByAlarmnr(item.alarmnr)">
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Or you can define an object/ a map with key, value pairs for the right colors :

```
let colors = {
  1:'red'
  2:'blue'
  3:'yellow',
  4:'green'
}
```

and in the html :

```
 <table *ngFor="let item of notif">
   <tr class="cell" [style.border-color]="colors[item.alarmnr]">
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can create a function in ts file 
and return class or style on your logic to a variable and use that variable 
to `[style.border-color] ="yourvariable"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using ngClass for this

```
<table *ngFor="let item of notif">
  <tr class="cell" [ngClass]="{'red': item.alarmnr === 1, 
   'blue': item.alarmnr === 2, 
   'yellow': item.alarmnr === 3,
   'green' : item.alarmnr === 4}">
  </tr>
</table
```